# JS Why doesn't this nested for loop function properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I can't figure out what the problem with this for loop is. The code looks okay to me, but the nested loop doesn't increment the value peakAverage correctly.

```
// Update bar data
for (let i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {

    let peakAverage = 0;

    if (settings.bars.barsAmount < 7) {

        for (let j = 64 / (Math.pow(2, settings.bars.barsAmount) * i); j < 64 / (Math.pow(2, settings.bars.barsAmount) * (i + 1)); j++) {

            peakAverage += finalProcessing[j];
        }

        peakAverage /= 64 / Math.pow(2, settings.bars.barsAmount)

        bars[i].desiredHeight = peakAverage * canvas.height / 3 + 1;
    }
}
```

The code should get values from the `finalProcessing` array depending on the length of the `bars` array, in a way that for each element of the `bars` array, a portion of the `finalProcessing` array is iterated, and then calculate the average of the values.

Comment: You need to explain what this code should perform? Syntactically, it looks okay. But the condition `j<...` will probably never execute.

Comment: Hard to understand your code because we lack information about `bars`, `settings` and `finalProcessing`

Comment: @DumbCoder7 and @Guerric P, `bars` is an array with possible lengths of 2^x. `settings.bars.length` is the exponent of 2. And finally, `finalProcessing` is an array with a fixed length of 64.

Comment: Oh, it should be `settings.bars.barsAmount` in the last comment.

Comment: Unless `i` is negative, `64 / (Math.pow(2, settings.bars.barsAmount) * (i + 1))` is always smaller than `64 / (Math.pow(2, settings.bars.barsAmount) * i)`, so the loop will never iterate.

Comment: @Bergi care to elaborate? I can't figure out how it can be smaller, because for example if `settings.bars.barsAmount` was to be 5, and `i` was to be 1, then `64 / 2^5 * 1 = 2`, and `64 / 2^5 * (1 + 1) = 4`.

Comment: @JoniHelén You have `64 / (2^5 * 1)` and `64 / (2^5 * 2)`

Comment: @Bergi That was it! the code works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bergi for pointing out that my calculation formula was incorrect. The correct formulae should be `(64 / Math.pow(2, settings.bars.barsAmount)) * i` and `(64 / Math.pow(2, settings.bars.barsAmount)) * (i + 1)` and NOT `64 / (Math.pow(2, settings.bars.barsAmount) * i)` and `64 / (Math.pow(2, settings.bars.barsAmount) * (i + 1))`.